# Efficient way of reading in list of string csvs' into lists

Tags: python, performance, csv

I have a list of strings. Each string is a comma separated list of numbers. I want to quickly convert each of these strings into a list. So far I have done the following:

#### My Solution So Far

```
def convertCommaSeperatedStringToList(data):

    s_lists = []

    for s in data:
        s_list =  [int(x) for x in s.split(',')]
        s_lists.append(s_list)
```

#### Example Dataset

```
# Here we have 600 very long lists to process
import numpy as np

data = []

for x in range(0,600):
    a = (np.random.randint(1000,size=100000)).tolist()
    b = ','.join(str(x) for x in a)
    data.append(b)
```

Just some background if you're wondering why I would have such a wierd list, I am reading this list from a downstream database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fastest way would be to use a list-comprehension here. This would avoid the repetitive lookups to `list.append` and will use the [`LIST_APPEND`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-LIST_APPEND) byte code.

```
s_lists = [[int(x) for x in row.split(',')] for row in data]
```

Note that for function names [underscores are preferred over camel-case](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles).

Comment: Thanks that worked well.compression seems to be the trick

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, list comprehension is the fastest way to solve this. However, I'd just like to point out that you should also consider using a [generator function](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/292/generators#t=201707312118124682651) if it suits your needs to prevent the need to load the entire dataset.

```
def convertCommaSeparatedStringToList(data):
    for s in data:
        yield [int(x) for x in s.split(',')]
```